# css : image-text alignment problem

Tags: css

could anyone provide me a solution to align this correctly
http://jsfiddle.net/zEM7J/3/
so that the text appears in the middle of the image. right now its kind of in the bottom

Thanks

Comment: According to your fiddle, you're trying to align the DIV, not the IMG...is that what you meant?

Comment: It seems like you need vertical alignment.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Keoki Zee we need to apply vertical align to the text and not to the img right and the problem is if I put my image outside div then the image appears on the next line

Comment: use text-align: center; to align the text in the center of the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
<img src="" style="vertical-align:middle;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zEM7J/8/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="a" style="background: url("")>axasxasx</div>
```

CSS:

```
#a
{
    background: #color url("path to image") center center no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to change the CSS to:

```
#a img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This will cause the text to be aligned vertically with the middle of the image.